# How do I get my checkbox to update correctly with localStorage?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a website where I need to save the checkbox, but update it every second. I ran into this bug which loads the checkbox in the same way, even if I uncheck it. Is there a way to have it update correctly? I'm guessing there is probably an easy way. I've tried a bunch of methods.

This is my code so far:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" onClick="runa()">
          <script>
            var dathing = false;
            function runa() {
              if(localStorage.getItem("checked1") === "true") {
              localStorage.setItem("checked1", "false")
              dathing = false
              } else
              if(localStorage.getItem("checked1") === "false") {
              localStorage.setItem("checked1", "true")
              dathing = true
              }
            }
            function lalala() {
              var checkboxa1 = document.getElementById("checkbox1")
              if(dathing === true) {
                checkboxa1.checked="true"
              } else if(dathing === false) {
                checkboxa1.checked="false"
              }
            }
            setInterval(() => lalala(), 1000)
          </script>
```

Thanks for any help!!

I tried using a different checkbox with a different function, but that just messed up the whole process. I also looked in the Developer console, and even when the checkbox is false, it reloads to be checked.

Comment: Call `runa` from inside `lalala` to keep localStorage in sync with the auto-updates.

Comment: Good suggestion about keeping everything in sync.

Comment: I tried this, it didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just setting the checkbox state to whatever is saved in LocalStorage?

```
function lalala() {
var checkboxa1 = document.getElementById("checkbox1");
checkboxa1.checked = dathing;
}
```

If you want to also improve the runa function, I suggest something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" onclick="runa()">
<script>
  var dathing = localStorage.getItem("checked1") === "true";
  var checkboxa1 = document.getElementById("checkbox1");
  checkboxa1.checked = dathing;
  
  function runa() {
    dathing = !dathing;
    localStorage.setItem("checked1", dathing);
  }
  
  setInterval(() => {
    dathing = localStorage.getItem("checked1") === "true";
    checkboxa1.checked = dathing;
  }, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: This is better, now I'm having another issue in which when I reload the page the checkbox doesn't stay where it was before. I do have a localStorage variable, though.